# How do I change submit URL for exposed search filter?

Tags: 7, views, forms, search

I've created view using Search API Views with two different displays.

First *Page* display (`by_terms`) and with the following options:

> *Page settings*: Path:/taxonomy/term/%
>
> *Contextual filters*: Category: Term ID (indexed)
>
> *Filter criteria*: Search: Fulltext search (exposed)

And second *Content pane* display (`panel_pane`):

> *Use Panel path*: Yes
>
> *Filter criteria*: Search: Fulltext search (exposed)
>
> *Link display*: Custom URL set to `search/results`

---

When I open page with 1st display `/category/list/name` (which is alias to `/taxonomy/term/123`) and submit Search input, it goes to `/category/list/name?keywords=test`.

When I open page with 2nd display (`/search/results`) and submit Search input, it goes to `/taxonomy/term/%2A?keywords=test` which is weird.

Ideally I would like the submit to end up in both cases at `/search/results?keywords=test`.

---

Is there any way of controlling the submit URL of the landing page for exposed filter? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that specific problem is with [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/node/419556).

The exposed form is basically a block which have no sense of context, therefore setting the URL from the view pane doesn't affect exposed filters in a block.

Therefore one way to go is to use `hook_form_alter`:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function foo_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    $form['#action'] = current_path();
  }
}
```

Or:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter().
 */
function foo_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-foo-default') { // Or: if ($form['#action'] === '/foo')
    $form['#action'] = '/bar';
  }
}
```

Or by [extending Views handler](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/user_addressbook/tree/modules/includes/views/handlers/user_addressbook_field_handler_user_address_commerce_checkout_select.inc?id=1ce5954fe30cab35c2f54d8ee76e86b8c1721107), for example:

```
class foo_handler extends views_handler_field {

  /**
   * Add to and alter the form.
   */
  function views_form(&$form, &$form_state) {

    // Submit to the current page if not a page display.
    if ($this->view->display_handler->plugin_name != 'page') {
      $form['#action'] = current_path();
    }
  }

}
```

Alternatively content pane can be used which can override the path, instead of using exposed form. See this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/419556) for more details.