# How to avoid Drupal redirecting my multilingual Views pages?

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n, redirection

I've got a [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) page in a multilingual website where I need a different url for each language, ie:

- es: mysite/apartamentos.
- en: mysite/appartments.
- fr: mysite/appartements.
- ru: mysite/arendu.

I created an url alias for each language (which is mysite/appartments although the default language of my site is spanish) so the spanish alias for `appartments` is `apartamentos` and so on. I created these aliases using `configuration >> Search and Metadata >> URL aliases >> add alias`.

I have to pass query parameters to the view to filter the results so my url is something like mysite/en/appartments/p/location_field/2 and I've got a form where I manually put the action like :

`echo "/".$language."/".$translated_page`

where translated page may be apartamentos, appartments, appartements or arendu, making the action url :

/es/apartamentos , /fr/appartements , /en/appartments and /ru/arendu

My problem is that when this form is sent Drupal sends me to

> mysite/es/appartments/p/location_field/2

instead of

> mysite/es/apartamentos/p/location_field/2

and the same occurs for all the languages. The rest of the thing seem fine and even the breadcrumb (which is generated using the url) looks correct (
Inicio >> Apartamentos Costa Dorada, in Spanish).

When I use the language switch it redirects me to the correct translated page but without the query parameters (from `mysite/es/appartments/p/location_field/2` it sends me to `mysite/es/apartamentos`).

I don't know what can be causing this issue, maybe the query parameters interfering with the alias interpretation?

**Note**: I have a lot of translation modules enabled. For the [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) modules there are: block, field, menu, node, path, string, taxonomy, translation (translation sets), variable and views.

Comment: have a look here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22989/changing-url-of-exposed-filter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## i18n_path submodule

I assume you're also using the [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module. So make sure you also enabled the `i18n_path` submodule (= Path translation). More details about it, from the [community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1279392) (bold markup added here):

> ... allows you to map together existing pages that are translations of each other. This will allow users to use the language switcher to navigate between the associated pages.
>
> The module is meant to be used as a last resort to translate paths that can't otherwise be mapped together as translations. For example, paths to translated nodes can already be linked with the Content translation module and paths to translated taxonomy terms can be linked with the Taxonomy translation module. **Path translations should be used to link generic paths, such as those provided by Views** or Panels.
>
> To set up translations of a particular path, you need to create a path translation set by going to Configuration > Regional and language > Translation sets > Paths and clicking Add path translation.

## i18n page views

You may also want to check if you can get it to work using the [i18n page views](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18_page_views) module. Some details from its project page:

> ... provides a new display of views, where you can select different paths for each language enabled on your site, so a view has a localized route for each language.

**Note 1**: "*if you cannot find any option in the view to translate the path*" (as in your comment below), then you may want to have a look at what's mentioned in [Comment #1 of issue 2389535](https://www.drupal.org/node/2389535#comment-9415163), which states:

> ... May be you have chosen a page display rather than a i18n page display when you created your view. Please be sure that you selected the correct views display. I attach some screenshots for helping:

**Screenprint 1**:

[image]

**Screenprint 2**:

[image]

**Note 2**: To answer the question about "*Will I have to create the whole view page again to make it as an i18n_page?*" (as in one of your (now deleted) comments below this answer), I would give it a try using either of the approaches described in the answers to the question at 
[How to duplicate a Views display (which is not the master) as a different display type?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192120/) ... If that doesn't work / apply, then recreation of the whole view page seems like the only option left.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the path-alias and try coding this special case yourself, using

[hook_url_inbound_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7.x) and or [hook_url_outbound_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7.x)

> or just do your own paths via custom page callbacks (hook_menu) and
>   then show the view with views_embed_view.

You could also alter the action of the exposed filter's form:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function foo_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    $form['#action'] = current_path();
  }
}
```

Or:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter().
 */
function foo_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-foo-default') { // Or: if ($form['#action'] === '/foo')
    $form['#action'] = '/bar';
  }
}
```

Taken form here [How do I change submit URL for exposed search filter?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/156043/how-do-i-change-submit-url-for-exposed-search-filter)